# Steps for evaluating complex integrals?

Tags: integration

What are the steps for  evaluating complex integral $\int e^{2ix}dx$? We know that $$\int e^{2ix}dx=\frac{e^{2ix}}{2i}.$$

Comment: Looks like you've done it! Of course, one needs to consider the contour of integration.

Comment: I only know the result, but don't know how to evaluate it.

Comment: All the operations you can do with real numbers, you can do with complex ones too. You can solve this integral with substitution $u=2ix$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have already answered your own question. Suppose that $\gamma\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ is the path defined by, say, $\gamma(t)=t+ti$. Then$$\int_\gamma e^{2ix}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{e^{2i\gamma(1)}}{2i}-\frac{e^{2i\gamma(0)}}{2i}=\frac{e^{-2+2i}-e^0}{2i}.$$Not to mention, of course, that$$\int_{\frac12}^2e^{2ix}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{e^{4i}-e^i}{2i}.$$